# Proving that Sp(2N,R) is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, compactness, topological-groups

I'm working though Hall's *Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations* and I want to show that the matrix Lie group $Sp(2N,\mathbb{R})$ is not locally compact. I've already shown that it fails to be compact since it is not bounded. The text doesn't talk about local compactness at all. How would I go about proving this?

I know that $\mathbb{R}^d$ is locally compact and subspaces need not be locally compact. To prove the space is not locally compact it would suffice to show that there exists a matrix with no compact neighborhood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Lie group is a smooth manifold and each smooth manifold is locally compact.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake.